# How can i show all vertices in orientdb except where @class="movie"?

Tags: orientdb

Hi there i want to show all Vertices except the ones called movie.
my statement so far was

```
 SELECT * FROM V WHERE NOT @class="movie"
```

but unfortunately the response does not contain any records. can anybody explain this to me ? :) Thank you :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Cool i solved it by using:

SELECT * FROM V WHERE @class!="movie"

thanks for your help Idacrema :)

Answer (score 0):

what version are you using? If I try in 3.0.0 your query work but you have to use "class" :

SELECT * FROM V WHERE NOT @class="movie"

Comment: i downloaded just 5 days ago, i have "OrientDB 2.2.31 Community", in the website they say 3.0.0 is for testing purposes only :) so good to know that this will be addressed :)  so SELECT * FROM V WHERE NOT @class="movie" will be the right query then ? :)

Comment: I retried the response and i rephrased my question a little, because, the problem is not that the querie is not valid, the problem is that the response does not contain any records 0:) but im sure that that i have 4 different classes in my db :)